# How to tag m4a music with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, itunes, tagging, m4a

I have to tag a m4a song using nodejs.

I looked an already tagged file, and I though that it would be as easy as opening the file and writting the tags in the ilst section... but no.

Can anyone explain it for stupid people like? is there any library or package for doing it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try this package called `jsmediatags` for adding metadata to your files.

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg could be an option.
It has a wrapper for calling it from node, or you could just spawn processes.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg
https://ffmpeg.org/